# Keep getting Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Tags: php

I keep getting this warning:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
here is my full code which performe function list output from mysql and paging it 10 output per page , the error appear in last page

```
<?php
    require_once('dbconnect.php');

    $yesterday = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("yesterday")); 
    $page=intval($_POST['p']);
    if($page=='')
    {
        $page=1;    
    } 
    $dbadd=($page-1)*10;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM ranking";
    $totalposts=mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($query));
    $totalpages=ceil($totalposts/10);
    $query = "SELECT  r.ranking,r.screenname,r.name,r.followers,r.tweets,r.location,r.`join    date`,r.avatar, h.date, r.followers-h.followers followers_diff, r.tweets-h.tweets tweets_diff  FROM ranking r, ranking_hist h WHERE r.screenname=h.screenname and h.date='$yesterday' AND r.ranking>$dbadd AND r.ranking<($dbadd+11) ORDER BY ranking ASC LIMIT 10 ";

    $result = mysql_query($query);

    if( !$result ) {
    die("Error: " . mysql_error() );
    } 

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    $tweep = $row['screenname']; 
    $tweeps[$tweep] = $row; 
    }

    $query = "SELECT r.ranking,r.screenname,r.name,r.followers,r.tweets,r.location,r.`join date`,r.avatar  FROM ranking r  WHERE r.screenname NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT screenname from ranking_hist ) AND r.ranking>$dbadd AND r.ranking<($dbadd+11)  ORDER BY ranking ASC LIMIT 10";

     $result = mysql_query($query);
     if( !$result ) {
    die("Error: " . mysql_error() );
     } 

     while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    echo "";
    $tweep = $row['screenname']; 
    $tweeps[$tweep] = $row; 
     }

     mysql_free_result($result);

     $i = 0;
     $total_amount = count($tweeps);

     foreach  ($tweeps as $tweep) {
         $i++;
         if ($total_amount == $i) {
             $class = 'divrow divrowlast';
         } else {
             $class = 'divrow';
         }

         $col5 = "";
     if( $tweep['followers_diff'] > 0 ) {                   
         $col5 = "<span style='color:green; display:inline;'> +" . $tweep['followers_diff'] . "▲ </span>";
         }
     else if( $tweep['followers_diff'] < 0 ) {
         $col5 = "<span style='color:red; display:inline;'> -" . $tweep['followers_diff'] . "▼ </span>";
         }

         $html_table .=   '<div class="'.$class.'"><ul>' .
             "<li class='row100rank'> " . $tweep['ranking'] . "</li>" .      
             "<li class='row100user'>
          <div class='avatar'><img width='32' height='32' src='" . $tweep['avatar'] . "' alt='" . $tweep['screenname'] ."' /></div>
          <div  class='feature-author'><a class='text_bigger' href='http://www.twitter.com/" . $tweep['screenname'] . "/'>@".$tweep['screenname']."</a></div>
        <div class='row100description'>".$tweep['name']."<br />".$tweep['location']."</div></li>" .
              "<li class='pad'><div class='stat'> <span>" . $tweep['followers'] . " $col5</span> followers</div></li>" .
              "<li class='pad rowTwitte'><div class='stat'> <span>" . $tweep['tweets'] . " $col6</span> tweets</div></li>" .
              "<li class='pad rowJoionDate'><div class='stat'> <span>" . date  ( 'd M y', strtotime($tweep['join date'])) . "</span> joindate</div></li>" .
              "</ul></div>";
          }

      echo $html_table;

?>

<div class="dataTables_paginate paging_full_numbers" ><span   class="first paginate_button" ><a class="pagelinks" href="javascript:void(0);" pageid="1" onClick="changepage(1);">First</a></span>
              <span class="previous paginate_button" ><a class="pagelinks" href="javascript:void(0);" pageid="<?php echo $page>1?($page-1):1;?>" onClick="changepage(<?php echo $page>1?($page-1):1;?>);" >Previous</a></span>

<span>
<?php
    switch($page){
        case 1:
             $it=1;
             $itl=6;
             break;
        case 2:
             $it=1;
             $itl=6;
         break;
        case $totalpages:
         $it=$totalpages-4;
         $itl=$totalpages+1;
            break;
        case $totalpages-1:
         $it=$totalpages-4;
         $itl=$totalpages+1;
         break;
        default:
         $it=$page-2;
         $itl=$page+3;
    }

    for(;$it<$itl;$it++){
?>
  <span class="<?php echo  $page== $it?'paginate_active':'paginate_button'; ?>"> 
      <a class="pagelinks" href="javascript:void(0);" pageid="<?php echo $it;?>" onClick="changepage(<?php echo $it;?>);" ><?php echo $it; ?></a></span>
<?php
   }
?>

  </span>
  <span class="next paginate_button" ><a class="pagelinks" href="javascript:void(0);" pageid="<?php echo $page<$totalpages?($page+1):$page;?>" onClick="changepage(<?php echo $page<$totalpages?($page+1):$page;?>);">Next</a>
  </span>

   <span class="last paginate_button" >
       <a class="pagelinks" href="javascript:void(0);" pageid="<?php echo $totalpages;?>" onClick="changepage(<?php echo $totalpages;?>);">Last</a>
   </span></div>

   <div class="dataTables_info"> 
        Showing <?php echo ($page-1)*10+1;?> to <?php echo ($page-1)*10+10;?> of <?php echo $totalposts;?> 
    </div>
```

Comment: $tweeps must not be an array or object then. Try var_dumping it or the like and see what it really is at that point.

Comment: could you tell us what $tweeps contains ?

Comment: `$tweeps` is not array or object. Can you show us where one is defined?

Comment: Off topic, but it's worth being aware that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated and not recommended for use. You should use either the equivalent `mysqli_xxx()` functions or the PDO library instead. Please see the PHP manual for more info.

Comment: @SDC will consider modify this once am done with fix :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code blow. Your $tweeps might on some occasions not be an array or object, check if the array is not empty and `is_array($tweeps)`.

```
$i = 0;
$total_amount = count($tweeps);
if(is_array($total_amount) && !empty($tweeps))
{
    foreach  ($tweeps as $tweep)
    {
        $i++;
        if ($total_amount == $i)
        {
           $class = 'divrow divrowlast';
        }
        else
        {
           $class = 'divrow';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ive modfied my post check it again , paging is not working when i modify with your code

Comment: the paging working but no data pulled in the 2nd page etc til last page !

Comment: you don't seem to be paginating it in the query. try changing `"LIMIT 10"` to `"LIMIT " .$page * 10.", 10"`;

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely to be that the query isn't retuning any data.

You are populating new entries into the `$tweeps` array inside the loop, but if there's no data, it won't ever go into that loop.

You aren't initialising the `$tweeps` variable anywhere else, so if it doesn't go into the loop, `$tweeps` won't be an array, it'll be undefined. This will then give you an error if you try to use it in a `foreach()`.

You need to add a line to initialise the variable before you start populating it:

```
$tweeps = array();
```

This would go somewhere above the loop where you first start populating `$tweeps`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: when i add array , before my loop the paging is not working its just pull 1st 10 $tweeps the next page appear empty !

Comment: I guess there are other bugs in the code then. I didn't look that far. The answer above is trying to fix the original problem, which is the error in the foreach().